# What can be the values for Heder_Search_Paths and Library_Search_Paths for UrbanAirship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, urbanairship.com

I have implemented the UrbanAirship in my App(with libUAirship-1.1.1.a).

I have specified the values of

```
   Header_Search_Paths=../Airship/**  (as reqursive)
```

and have not specified any value of

```
  Library_Search_Paths
```

But i am getting an error like-

```
  ld: library not found for -lUAirship-1.1.1
  Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

what can be the solution ? i am waiting for the answer.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `Library Search Path` but you can try with `-all_load` or `-ObjC`. else you can try [this link](http://urbanairship.com/docs/apns_test_client.html#set-up-a-new-application). And make sure you have added all the frameworks.

Comment: @Devang- thanks for replay. I have tried "this link" and i have also added all the frameworks. But i am still getting above error. In which directory we have to put the "libUAirship 1.1.1.a" library file ? and is there any setting that we have to do for complier or the simulator?

Comment: @Rohan : You have to add libUAirship* from your Urbanairship directory which you have added in your project.